# using MFC CMap for CString int pairs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm currently working on a DLL that needs to convert back and forth between the friendly name for a value and the value itself. As this code is used in many places throughout the codebase, I want to try and keep it simple and in a single function or object so I only have to declare them once.

From my reading it looks like `CMap` is the tool for the job, but I can't seem to discover any combination of template arguments that compiles without errors.

My values are `CString` and `int`.  I tried the following definition:

```
CMap<int, int, CString, CString> encodermap;
```

which compiles, but when I try to add a value:

```
encodermap["Encoder 1"] = 0;
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2501: 'encodermap' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
error C2040: 'encodermap' : 'int []' differs in levels of indirection from 'CMap<KEY,ARG_KEY,VALUE,ARG_VALUE>'
```

I've tried changing the `CMap` to this:

```
CMap<CString, CString, int, int> encodermap;
```

but I get the same four errors.

I'm sure I must be missing something but I'm at a loss as to what.

Because of the SDK being used for this work I'm require VS2003

Answer (score 6):

**The problem**

I think you've inverted the key type and the valye type.

Your original declaration defines `int` as being the key to be searched for with `operator[]`. So `encodermap[0] = "Encoder 1";` would work.

But when your compiler sees  `encodermap["Encoder 1"] = 0;`, he tries to find an `operator[]` which takes char* (or something to which char * can be converted to) and returns an int.  The last error message tells you that he couldn't find such an operator for your map.

With MSVC 2015, the error message is more concise: [C2679](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1925w4w.aspx).

**The solution**

You should define your [`CMap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z.aspx) with a `CString` key and an `int` value.  The trick to know, is that for a `CString` KEY, the the ARG_KEY should be `LPCWSTR` .  So the right definition would be:

```
CMap<CString, LPCWSTR, int, int> encodermap;
```

This permits to use `CString` as key in the map's [`operator[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htba4sd6.aspx).

Now if you use MFC on windows, you probably use UNICODE and wide chars (therefore the LPCWSTR instead of LPCSTR).  When calling the operator you then have either to use a CString or a wide literal:

```
        encodermap[L"Encoder 1"] = 0;
        encodermap[CString("Encoder 2")] = 1;
```

Comment: You may also be interested in further reading about [CMap How-to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13458/CMap-How-to)

Comment: Instead of `CString` you should use `CStringW`, to match the encoding for `LPCWSTR`. You can still construct a `CStringW` from a narrow character string literal, i.e. `CStringW("Encoder 2")` (although that is somewhat error prone).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, int, int> encodermap;
```

This CodeProject article [CMap How-to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13458/CMap-How-to) may be of some help.

> Many people get confused about CMap's declaration `CMap < KEY, ARG_KEY,
>   VALUE, ARG_VALUE >`, why not just `CMap < KEY, VALUE >`?
>
> In fact, the ultimate data container in `CMap` is `CPair`, and the
>   internal of `CPair` is `{KEY, VALUE}`. Therefore, `CMap` will really store a
>   `KEY`, and not `ARG_KEY`. However, if you check with the MFC source code,
>   almost all the internal parameters passing within `CMap` itself is
>   called with `ARG_KEY` and `ARG_VALUE`, therefore, using `KEY &` as `ARG_KEY`
>   seems always a correct thing, except when:
>
> - You are using primitive date types like `int`, `char`, where pass-by-value makes no difference (may be even faster) with
>     pass-by-reference.
> - If you use `CString` as `KEY`, you should use `LPCTSTR` as `ARG_KEY` and not `CString &`, we will talk more about this later.

Edit: Cristophe, another option  for the assignment is `encodermap[_T("Encoder 1")] = 0;`, which will work for single-byte, multi-byte or Unicode with the `LPCTSTR` typedef. You will also need to `#include <tchar.h>`.